# ASP.NET MVC : does a partial know if it is bring requested from another page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partial view which can either be requested via an Action (Action2 in the image below), or rendered inside another page with "Html.Action()" (Action1 in the image below). From within the partial (or the partials controller) is there a way to determine which of these two methods were used to render the page?

[image]

Comment: Everyone who tried to answer this question, I was very new to ASP.NET MVC when I asked this question, and despite my best attempts to clarify my question at the time it is obvious now that I had no idea what was going on. I have a few months experience now and have re-written the question to make some sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [ControllerContext.IsChildAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.ischildaction.aspx) or check `DataTokens` whether there is something with key `"ParentActionViewContext"` if you don't have access to `ControllerContext`.

Comment: That's only true if you use `Html.Action` to render child actions, but doesn't help if you use `Html.Partial` to render the partial.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get it from

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl
```

Comment: You could have a controller action which in some cases returns a main view which in turn renders the partial and in other cases directly return the partial view specifying its full path. In both cases `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` will be the same inside this partial.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that it is not particularly good practise to do this sort of thing in MVC. The partial should not be concerned about its "parent" ... but if you do need to do this, for whatever reason ...

You can use this code in the partial view's controller to determine if it was loaded directly or included in another page.

```
// this is the route which was originally used to route the request
string req_controller = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
string req_action = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

// this is the route which was used to route to this action/view
string this_controller = RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
string this_action = RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

if (req_controller == this_controller && req_action == this_action)
{
  // this partial was loaded directly
}
else
{
  // this partial was loaded indirectly
}
```

Comment: This will not work. Try writing the following controller action: `public ActionResult Index(bool? directly) { if (directly != null && directly.Value) return PartialView("MyPartial"); else return View(); }`. Now in the `Index.cshtml` view render the partial. When you invoke this action with the boolean parameter equals to false it will render the Index view which in turn will include the partial containing your code. Then try passing true so that you render the partial directly. In both cases your first `if` condition will be satisfied.

Comment: @Darwin: you are absolutely correct with your understanding of my question, however I meant something slightly different, and could have perhaps explained a bit better. By "requested directly" I mean via URL. so "http://mysite/home/_partial" vs "http://mysite/home/index" (which includes the partial).

Comment: you cannot request a partial directly. Views residing inside the Views folder are never served. You must always pass through a controller action. So an url such as `mysite/home/_partial` simply doesn't make sense unless of course `_partial` is an action defined on the `Home` controller.

Comment: It does have an action defined in the home controller.

Comment: OK, so what does this action do? It returns a partial?

Comment: It does a small bit of logic and returns the partial, yes.

Answer (score 1):

my reason for wanting to know this is that I wanted to be able to switch the `Layout` of a partial view based on whether or not it was rendered from a controller action or from within another page.

ie.

```
return PartialView("MyView.cshtml");
```

would result in a layout with the requisite menu bars and other site trimmings.

and

```
@Html.Partial("MyView")
```

would just embed the content without adding the rest of the page.

so, in my page's default Layout I have:

```
@if (this.IsPartial()) {
    Layout = null;
} else {
    Layout = "_SiteLayout";
}
@RenderBody()
```

here's what I found:

```
public static bool IsPartialResult(this WebPageBase @this)
{
    return !@this.OutputStack.Any(writer => writer is HttpWriter);
}
```

it probably won't work in all situations. but it works for me. YMMV/HTH

Comment: Another, admittedly rubbish, way of dealing with this is to set a flag around the @Html.Partial logic and pick up on it in the 'Layout =' code. It's valid in our case because we have very few of these kinds of cases

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way and a partial shouldn't *need to know it*.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting explaining why you think the answer is wrong.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect (there is a way) and does not actually answer the question in any way (I'm not asking about whether it is good practice).

Comment: @Nippysaurus, see my comment on your answer for a counter example.